# Помощь с freetype

Tags: c++, directx

Я стараюсь загрузить шрифт для отрисовки текста с помощью freetype, для DX ничего не нашел, а для OpenGL что-то да есть, стараюсь перевести код в DX,

Сейчас структура выглядит так

```
Font::Font(  Graphics& gfx )
{
    namespace wrl = Microsoft::WRL;

    auto error = FT_Init_FreeType( &library );
    if ( error ) 
    {
        LOG_ERROR( "FreeTyper error" );
    }
    error = FT_New_Face(library,
        "Engine\\assets\\fonts\\Ruda-Bold.ttf",
        0,
        &face);
    if ( error )
    {
        LOG_ERROR("FreeTyper error");
    }
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);
    // load first 128 characters of ASCII set
    for (unsigned char c = 0; c < 128; c++)
    {
        // Load character glyph 
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
        {
            LOG_ERROR("FreeTyper error");
            continue;
        }

        // create texture resource
        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc = {};
        textureDesc.Width = face->glyph->bitmap.width;
        textureDesc.Height = face->glyph->bitmap.rows;
        textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
        textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
        textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
        textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
        textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
        textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
        textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

        D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA sd = {};
        sd.pSysMem = face->glyph->bitmap.buffer;
        sd.SysMemPitch = face->glyph->bitmap.width * face->glyph->bitmap.rows;
        wrl::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> pTexture;
        HRESULT hr;

        GFX_THROW_NOINFO( GetDevice( gfx )->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, &sd, &pTexture ) );
    }
}
```

Но face->glyph->bitmap.buffer, face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows по нулям, все ли я делаю вообще правильно?

Comment: Для текста есть замечательный [DirectWrite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/programming-guide).

Comment: @user7860670 он же вроде использует GDI?

Comment: @AlexF я бы хотел разобраться именно с freetype

Comment: Оно ничего не использует, однако есть интероп с GDI, Direct2d или можно свой кастомный написать.

Comment: @user7860670 Хорошо, спасибо. Но все же, хотелось бы разобраться с библиотекой этой, есть какие-то идеи?

Comment: Например при вызове `FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes` указывается 0 ширина пикселя, а результат не проверяется.

Comment: @user7860670 пытался указать другое значение, да и в примерах тоже 0 указан